# Creating a list of square of numbers in a given range

Tags: python, list

Edit: Sorry guys, I meant to use the power function, not squaring, i hope this clears it up

I'm a new to python, and I'm trying to create a function that lets the user input x and y and will give the output of the powers of those numbers in a loop, so `create_list(2,8)` returns the list `[1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256]`.

I have this code so far, but I feel like it's way off as it only allows for 1 input, whereas I'm looking for 2

```
import math

a=int(input())
while a<=10000:
  print (a)
  a=a*2
```

An example output of this is if a=4, output:

```
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
1024
2048
4096
8192
```

Comment: `base, exps = 2,8; for exp in range(exps): print(base**exp)`

Comment: Not entirely clear to me if you want squares or powers of 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous answers already explain how to solve your question, here I explain how to create a function. Notice that for simple operation like power, you don't need `import math`. With the following code you define a function `create_list(x, y)` that takes as input 2 numbers `x` and `y` and gives your output, regardless of how they are passed to the function:

```
def create_list(x, y):
    my_list = []
    for i in range(y+1):
        my_list.append(x**i)
    return my_list
```

After that, you can call the `create_list` function by giving the numbers programmatically (maybe they are the results of previous operations), but if you want to give them explicitly by keyboard, use this code:

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())

my_list = create_list(x,y)

print(my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

[ x * x for x in range (int(input("lower bound")), int(input("upper bound")))]

The above is a list comprehension. It takes every element in range and accesses it through the variable x. The expression on the left is what will actually end up in the list. For example, putting x + 1 would result in storing a value 1 greater than x being stored.

Inputs are evaluated from left to right so you can directly put them in as the parameters to the range function.

The evaluation order is:

Call 'lower bound' input

Convert to int

As above for right input

Evaluate range

Run list comprehension

Comment: Why don't you explain what the code does instead of just dumping it

Answer (score 0):

First, use the `input()` function twice to let the user input two numbers.

Use the formula `square = x * x` (instead of x*2) to calculate the square.

Iterate over all numbers between `a` and `b` by using the `range(a, b)` function.

Collect all square numbers in a list and print the list afterwards.

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())

squares = []

for i in range(a, b):
    square = i * i
    squares.append(square)

print(squares)
```

The more pythonic way in one line:

```
squares = [i*i for i in range (a,b)]
print(squares)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=int(input())
b=int(input())

def create_list(a,b):
    return [a**i for i in range(b+1)]

print(create_list(a,b))
```

output for `create_list(2,8)`

```
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python `pow` function

```
import math


def get_powers(power, length):
    return [int(math.pow(power, x)) for x in range(1, length + 1)]


power_input = int(input('power:'))
length_input = int(input('length:'))

print(get_powers(power_input, length_input))
```

run

```
power:3
length:5
[3, 9, 27, 81, 243]
```